# Making ordered heat maps in qplot (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making heat maps from correlations. I have two columns that represent ID's and a third column that gives the correlation between those two datapoints. I am struggling to get qplot to keep the order of my data in the file. Link to data:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3l9p1od5vjt0p4d/SNPS.txt?n=7399684

Here is the code I am using to make the plot:

```
test <- qplot(x=x, y=y, data=PCIT, fill = col1, geom = "tile")
```

I have tried several order options but they don't seem to do the trick? Ideas?

Thanks and Happy Holidays

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the levels of the factors `x` and `y` to be in the order you want them (as they come in from the file). Try

```
PCIT$x <- factor(PCIT$x, levels=unique(as.character(PCIT$x)))
```

and similarly with `y`.